# Adicionar ponteiro a um std::vector

Tags: c++, arduino

Oi,
preciso adicionar em um `vector<TimedCommand> tCommands;` referências de acesso para instâncias TimedCommand, exemplo:

```
    TimedCommand command1("*.*.*.*.*.*",&sonCommand,"13"); 
    (...)
    tCommands.push_back(&command1);
```

Infelizmente, quando faço isso acontece um `no matching function for call to 'std::vector<TimedCommand', std::allocator<TimedCommand>>:: push_back(TimedCommand*)`

Estou utilizando a lib [Standard C++ for Arduino](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus) e [Arduino Cron Library](https://github.com/punkle/ArduinoCronLibrary/).
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Axo que seu problema está nas tipagens. Você espera receber um objeto TimedCommand, e quando você passa a referencia você está passando um TimedCommand*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando adicionar um ponteiro a um `std::vector` de objetos "normais".

```
std::vector<TimedCommand> tCommands;
TimedCommand command1(...);
tCommands.push_back( &command1 ); //Erro de compilação
```

A última linha tenta converter um `TimedCommand*` em `TimedCommand`, o que é inválido.

Você tem duas opções: mudar seu `std::vector` para armazenar ponteiros

```
std::vector<TimedCommand*> tCommands;
TimedCommand *command1 = new TimedCommand(...); //Alocação dinâmica
tCommands.push_back( command1 );
```

O que implica em gerenciamento manual de memória, ou adicionar uma cópia de sua variável ao `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<TimedCommand> tCommands;
TimedCommand command1(...);
tCommands.push_back( command1 );
```

O que pode invalidar alguma lógica de seu algoritmo, ou não.